# how to create a html button to call a css script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a button that will call a css script to change the background image of the page

I have tried several things and have had some success with

````
function changecss(sheet){
    document.getElementById('backimage').setAttribute('href', sheet);
        
}
</script>

<link id="backimage" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">``

and

        ```<button type="button" onclick="changecss('bg2.css');">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><b>Change BG</button> 
 
        <button type="button" onclick="changeBodyBg('black');">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><b>&nbsp;Black&nbsp;&nbsp; </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeBodyBg('red');">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><b>&nbsp;Red&nbsp;&nbsp; </button>
        </b></font><button type="button" onclick="changeBodyBg('orange');">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><b>Orange</b></font> </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeBodyBg('yellow');">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><b>Yellow</button>
        </b></font>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeBodyBg('green');">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><b>Green</button>
        </b></font>```
        
**The problem is that it works if it is the first option chosen but, 
if I select any of the other buttons, which all work, then it does not work**

(css stylesheet code is: ```body {
background: ##1baa00;
background-image: url("zenbg-1.png"), url("zenbg-2.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}```
````

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: have tried many things - tried putting the link in a function then calling it, tried using form command but nothing I do seems to call it from a button command

Answer (score 1):

In a JavaScript `<script>` tag, make a function and instead of

```js
document.body.style.cssText+=';background-image: url(ZenBG-1.png);background-repeat: round;';
```

try

```js
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(ZenBG-1.png)';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat =  'round';
```

Comment: this works up to a point - thanks for the background-repeat command. I was using just repeat. The problem is that it still distorts the image. The css code is actually ```body {
background: ##1baa00;
background-image: url("zenbg-1.png"), url("zenbg-2.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}``` I am just a beginner and couldn't translate this into html so thought it would be sufficient to call the link function which I use in the header but have been unable to do so

Comment: Can you please share your code then through codepen.io or something similar so I can easily see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing directly with CSS text, try using a class in your CSS and toggling it.

```css
body {
  background: url('Some Image');
}

body.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.body.classList.toggle('red')">Red</button>
```